# how can i separate dupliverts object on the circle

Tags: materials, parent

after dupliverts of plank how can i separate duplicated object to independent object

[image]

Comment: The operator is "Make duplicate real": in object mode, Shift+Ctrl+A or in the menu "Object/Apply/Make duplicate real". Once done the objects will share their geometry (like in alt+D duplication), if you also want the geometry to be independent, use "Make single user" in the object menu whilst the dupli are selected.

Answer (score 2):

- Select circle.
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> Make Duplicates Real